# AND clause after an OR clause

Tags: mysql

I am trying to running an MySQL Query with a "FIND_IN_SET" in it.

Running the query works, But I also need to find "user_optin" where it is equal to 1.

Running this query currently finds people who have user_optin as "0"

```
SELECT `user_id`, `user_firstname`, `user_surname`, `user_email`, `user_type`, `user_optin`
FROM (`users`)
WHERE `user_type` =  'Volunteer'
AND 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(1, user_interests)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(2, user_interests)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(5, user_interests)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(6, user_interests)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(7, user_interests)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(8, user_interests)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(10, user_interests)
AND 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(1, user_activities)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(2, user_activities)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(4, user_activities)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(5, user_activities)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(11, user_activities)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(12, user_activities)
OR 1 <=FIND_IN_SET(14, user_activities)
AND `user_optin` =  '1'
```

If I take the "OR's" out of the query the user_optin part of the query works.

Is there anyway at all I can make the user_optin explict to find a "1" entry, Not a "0" entry.

I didn't design this database and I realise that find_in_set is not the best method for MySQL database queries.

Cheers

Comment: Perhaps wrap all the previous `WHERE` clauses in parenthesis to explicitly 'split' the clauses up?

Comment: Hi @ʰᵈˑhow do I achieve that? I have written this query as ORM but can make it an RAW MySQL query instead

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the other clauses within `()` to seperate them from the final `AND`.

```
SELECT
    `user_id`,
    `user_firstname`,
    `user_surname`,
    `user_email`,
    `user_type`,
    `user_optin`
FROM
    (`users`)
WHERE
    (
        `user_type` = 'Volunteer'
        AND 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(1, user_interests)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(2, user_interests)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(5, user_interests)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(6, user_interests)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(7, user_interests)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(8, user_interests)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(10, user_interests)
        AND 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(1, user_activities)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(2, user_activities)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(4, user_activities)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(5, user_activities)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(11, user_activities)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(12, user_activities)
        OR 1 <= FIND_IN_SET(14, user_activities)
    )
AND `user_optin` = '1'
```

Comment: Hi @hd Superb answer. Can this be written in an ORM query (I'm using Codeigniter in my project)

Comment: Thank you. Apologies, I've not worked with ORM framework or CodeIgniter. I would imagine so (with some edits)

Comment: No worries, appreciate your help!